# Xpages: Cannot get OnClick event in Navigator to fire

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am trying to build a dynamic navigator for a document database. The navigator build correctly by using a repeat node (I got this from a post by Per) and I can put page or basic nodes in the repeat node and everything looks good, but I need to set a scope variable and then refresh the view element, and I cannot get that code to fire.

I have included the code for the navigator below. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have scoured Stack Overflow and tried adding events manually all to no avail.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
        <xe:navigator
            id="navigator1"
            expandable="false">
            <xe:this.treeNodes>
                <xe:repeatTreeNode
                    var="navEntry"
                    indexVar="index"
                    loaded="true">
                    <xe:this.children>
                        <xe:pageTreeNode
                            rendered="true"
                            page="/xpViewAllDocs.xsp">
                            <xe:this.label><![CDATA[#{javascript:var dbName=@DbName();
var arr = @Unique(@Trim(@DbColumn(dbName,"alldocslookup",1)))
arr[index]}]]></xe:this.label>
                        </xe:pageTreeNode>
                    </xe:this.children>
                    <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var dbName=@DbName();
@Elements(@Unique(@Trim(@DbColumn(dbName,"alldocslookup",1))))}]]></xe:this.value>
                </xe:repeatTreeNode>    
            </xe:this.treeNodes>
            <xp:eventHandler
                event="onItemClick"
                submit="true"
                refreshMode="complete">
                <xe:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.put("key","Test");
view.postScript("alert('Client Side JavaScript executed!')");}]]></xe:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler></xe:navigator>
        </xp:view>
```

EDIT:

I tried all of the suggestions below but none of them worked.

I can get this to work by simply putting a link in the repeat or a computed field or something like that, but then it doesn't really look the navigation element at all. If I can just change the css some to make it look like the navigation I would be happy. I have taken a stab at it with a list container, but it is not working:

[image]

I feel like I am kind of close. What can I go to get this to look more like a navigator?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:list
        id="list1"
        styleClass="lotusMenuHeader">
        <xp:link
            role="menuItem"
            styleClass="lotusSelected"> All Documents</xp:link>
        <xp:link>Tag 1</xp:link>
        <xp:link>Tag 2</xp:link>
    </xe:list>
    <xp:panel>
        <ul
            header="lotusMenuHeader">
            <li
                class='lotusSelected'>Coffee</li>
            <li>Tea</li>
            <li>Milk</li>
        </ul>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: At least I can confirm that the onItemClick event does absolutely nothing, still investigating...

Comment: Thanks Oliver, I was getting damn irritated. Thought I did something wrong.

Comment: Not sure this is your issue, it seems unlikely, but I have had experiences where view.postscript was ignored for 'seemingly' no reason. Maybe this blog post I wrote from a few years ago will help:  http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2013/08/viewpostscript-only-works-for-certain.html

Comment: change refresh mode to partial... the complete one won't work, tested it recently for this issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/29928622/206265 and complete refresh did nothing.

Comment: Just wondering: try <xp:this.action> with related close tag instead of <xe:this.action>

Comment: Per, I tried that and unfortunately that didn't work either.

Comment: Frantisek, I changed it to partial and that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: I have edited my original question to see if I can do a workaround. Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onItemClick` doesn't seem to work with `pageTreeNode`. The event doesn't get rendered at all.

Use `basicLeafNode` instead. `onItemClick` does work with it well.
Put the current clicked value into sessionScope variable with `context.getSubmittedValue()`.
Redirect to you target XPage with `context.getSubmittedValue()`.

```xml
<xe:navigator
    id="navigator1"
    expandable="false">
    <xe:this.treeNodes>
        <xe:repeatTreeNode
            var="navEntry">
            <xe:this.children>
                <xe:basicLeafNode
                    label="#{navEntry}"
                    submitValue="#{navEntry}" />
            </xe:this.children>
            <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var dbName=@DbName();
                @Unique(@Trim(@DbColumn(dbName,"alldocslookup",1)))}]]></xe:this.value>
        </xe:repeatTreeNode>
    </xe:this.treeNodes>
    <xp:eventHandler
            event="onItemClick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xe:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                sessionScope.key = context.getSubmittedValue();
                context.redirectToPage("xpViewAllDocs.xsp")}]]></xe:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
</xe:navigator>
```